# How do I take a subset of a views Model and send the subset model to a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I take a subset of a views Model and send the subset model to a partial view?

I created a model, but the partial is looking for the parent model.

Am I creating this secondary subset model correctly?
How do I get the partial to see this secondary subset model?

Parent View code (not all):

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.BlogPublishedByBlogIdVM

        @* Create a subset model to send to the partial view. *@
        @{
            int parentBlogId = @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId;
            int parentLikeCount = @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.LikeCount;
            int parentDisLikeCount = @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.DisLikeCount;
            bool parentDisabledBoolean = @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.DisabledBoolean;
        }

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @* A partial view. Sending the subset model to the partial view. *@
                @Html.Partial("_BlogLikeAndDislike", @Model)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
```

Partial view code (not all):

```
<div>
@* Get the parent view's values that were passed via a model. *@
   <i class="BlogLike fa fa-my-size fa-thumbs-up"></i> | <i> @Model.LikeCount</i>
   <i class="BlogDisLike fa fa-my-size fa-thumbs-down"></i> | <i> @Model.DisLikeCount</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a new model e.g

```
public class ChildViewModel
{

        public int ParentBlogId {get; set;}
        public int ParentLikeCount = {get; set;}
        public int ParentDisLikeCount = {get; set;}
        public bool ParentDisabledBoolean = {get; set;}
}
```

Then you create the child model in parent view and pass the child view model when calling partial view

```
@Html.Partial("_BlogLikeAndDislike", childViewModel)
```

Finally set the model in Partial view

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.ChildViewModels
<div>
@* Get the parent view's values that were passed via a model. *@
   <i class="BlogLike fa fa-my-size fa-thumbs-up"></i> | <i> @Model.ParentLikeCount</i>
   <i class="BlogDisLike fa fa-my-size fa-thumbs-down"></i> | <i> @Model.ParentDisLikeCount</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, on your Razor Syntax. Declare your new instance of your Model which corresponds to the model on your Partial View:

```
   @{
      var entityPartial = new PartialViewModel(); //Make sure to complete the namespace here

      //Then attach the properties on your variable:
      entityPartial.parentBlogId = @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId;
    }
```

Afterwards, put this on your Partial HTML Helper, just pass the entity variable that you declare on the argument:

```
@Html.Partial("_BlogLikeAndDislike", entityPartial)
```

That's it. Make sure it `PartialViewModel` on my example here is the same model on your Partial View.

Comment: Willy, I can't seem to find the namespace where PartialViewModel() resides. It's not in System.Web.MVC.

Comment: That is just my example. Replace it with your Partial View model, since I don't know the ne of your model on your partial view on your example.